# NGINX: Ignoring Certain URL Parameters for Cache Purposes

Tags: nginx, cache

So say my NGINX cache key looks like this:

```
uwsgi_cache_key $scheme$host$request_method$request_uri;
```

... and that's mostly what I want. I want NGINX to make a cache key based on the entire URL, including the querystring. So that

```
https://example.com/?a=1&b=1
```

and

```
https://example.com/?a=1&b=2
```

... are separate pages, cached separately.

However, say that there are other parameters -- `c` and `d` -- that I don't want to affect the cache key. In other words, I want

---

### Case 1

```
https://example.com/
```

and

```
https://example.com/?c=1
```

and

```
https://example.com/?c=2
```

and

```
https://example.com/?c=1&d=2
```

... to return the same page from the cache.

---

### Case 2

And I want

```
https://example.com/?a=1
```

and

```
https://example.com/?a=1&d=2
```

and

```
https://example.com/?a=1&c=1&d=3
```

... to return the same page from the cache, which is different from the page in case 1.

---

I'm looking for a way to construct the `uwsgi_cache_key` so that it can account for these cases. I don't want to do it through redirects.

The number of parameters that I want to ignore when constructing the key -- `c` and `d`, in this example -- is limited; the number of number or parameters that I don't want to ignore is not.

How would you go about doing this? (Yes, this is mostly about `fbclid` and `utm_*` and their cousins.)

---

**UPDATE:**

Here is a rewrite of @tero-kilkanen's solution with `map`, in cases where `fbclid` and `launcher` are the undesired parameters. I don't know how much this slows down responses.

```
    map $args $cachestep1 {
        default $args;
        ~^(fbclid=[^&]*&?)(.*)$             $2;
        ~^([^&]*)(&fbclid=[^&]*)(&?.*)$     $1$3;
    }

    map $cachestep1 $cacheargs {
        default $cachestep1;
        ~^(launcher=[^&]*&?)(.*)$             $2;
        ~^([^&]*)(&launcher=[^&]*)(&?.*)$     $1$3;
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

I haven't tested an approach like this, but I think it could work:

```
map $args $cacheargs {
    ~^(.*)a=.+&(.*)$ $1$2;
}

map $cacheargs $cacheargs1 {
    ~^(.*)b=.+&(.*)$ $1$2;
}

uwsgi_cache_key $scheme$host$request_method$uri$cacheargs1;
```

First map removes `a=.+` from `$args` and records it to `$cacheargs`.

Second map removes `b=.+` from $cacheargs`and records it to`$cacheargs1`.

Then `$cacheargs1` is used as part of the cache key.

Original answer below.

---

You can use:

```
uwsgi_cache_key $scheme$host$request_method$uri$arg_a$arg_b;
```

This means that the cache key is built using normalized URI (without query arguments), and query arguments `a` and `b`.

Comment: That won't work for me. I have an unlimited number of possible arguments that I _do_ want to take into account for the cache key. I just need to winnow out a few.

Comment: In that case I think you need to implement a Lua script in nginx which will define the cache key with your logic into a variable, and then you use that variable for the directive.

Comment: I guess I was hoping there'd be some tricky stuff I could pull off with the `map` directive, maybe.

Comment: Now that you mentioned, there could be a `map` way. Check my updated answer.

Comment: Thanks! It's kludgy, but for now it's better than recompiling nginx with Lua support. Hope it's not killing my response time.

I rewrote your map blocks to account for cases when the undesired parameter comes first:

        `map $args $cachestep1 {
            default $args;
            ~^(fbclid=[^&]*&?)(.*)$             $2;
            ~^([^&]*)(&fbclid=[^&]*)(&?.*)$     $1$3;
        }

        map $cachestep1 $cacheargs {
            default $cachestep1;
            ~^(launcher=[^&]*&?)(.*)$             $2;
            ~^([^&]*)(&launcher=[^&]*)(&?.*)$     $1$3;
        }`