# NGINX: Ignoring fbclid parameter for FastCGI Cache Purposes

Tags: nginx, wordpress, cache, fastcgi

There are some good responses to this question here: [NGINX: Ignoring Certain URL Parameters for Cache Purposes](https://serverfault.com/questions/961844/nginx-ignoring-certain-url-parameters-for-cache-purposes/1062059)

But I cannot seem to get it to work. I'm running a wordpress install and here is my mapping:

```
map $args $cachestep1 {
  default $args;
  ~^(fbclid=[^&]*&?)(.*)$             $2;
  ~^([^&]*)(&fbclid=[^&]*)(&?.*)$     $1$3;
}
```

And my cachekey:

```
fastcgi_cache_key $scheme$host$request_method$uri$cachestep1;
```

I still get cache MISS on the exact same urls with different fbclids.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like the third regex is slightly wrong - `^([^&]*)(&fbclid=[^&]*)(&?.*)$` will not match string like `a=c&c=d&fbclid=trimm&xxx=yyy`.

It can be replaced with `^(.*)(&fbclid=[^&]*)(&?.*)$`. Try yourself on [regex101.com](https://regex101.com/r/L4uj7z/1).

Few small improvements:

- not capturing groups `(?:...)`
- `.*?` - not greedy version of `.*` (as little characters as possible)

```
map $args $cachestep1 {
  default $args;
  ~^(?:fbclid=[^&]*&?)(.*)$             $1;
  ~^(.*?)(?:&fbclid=[^&]*)(&?.*)$     $1$2;
}
```

Comment: This worked, thanks!